# Activity to RecyclerView Adapter Communication(Recyclerview in Fragment)

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I have a Activity which contains a fragment with recyclerview.
The recyclerview has few editable fields and need to put validations on clicking a button on activity.

Please let me know the solution or any techniques to overcome this problem statement

Comment: please add your recycler view code and the row you are using for recycler view as well.

Comment: You can use interface to communicate between fragment and its activity. For validation of fields in recyclerView row, is it possible to include a validation button in recyclerView row instead the activity? It would make it easier for you to access fields in recyclerView adapter and validate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data Between Fragments to Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439941/passing-data-between-fragments-to-activity)

Comment: @IshitaSinha Its not about passing data between fragment and activity. It's about a special scenario, where you have a recyclerview in fragment which has edittext and a button in activity. When the button is clicked we need to put a validation on edittext content.

Comment: You can check this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/35395780/2128166
it has also same context to pass data between components so have look to it.

Comment: If the button is in the activity and the edittext is in the fragment, then it *is* about passing data between fragment and activity.

Comment: @IshitaSinha edittext is in recyclerview

Comment: and the recycler view is in the fragment

Comment: @IshitaSinha recyclerview is in fragment only. The next button is in Activity. And the Recyclerview has a form containing Edittext and spinner. User enters name and select d gender from spinner. When i click next button i need to put a validatoin on form in recyclerview

Comment: which is exactly why I said it _is_ about passing data between fragment and activity.

Answer (score 0):

use this ([click here](http://square.github.io/otto/) ) functionality for data sharing between **Fragment** to **fragment** , **Fragment** to **Activity** and **Activity** to **Activity**

1) in your `onCreate` declare the `BUS`and register it

```
Bus bus = new Bus();
bus.register(this);
```

2) send data or any action using

```
bus.post(<your data or any Item>);
```

3) don't forgot to unregister in your `onestroy`

```
bus.unregister(this)
```

Comment: what about Activbity to Fragment or, Activity to Adapter class is it possible

Comment: if you declare the adapter class in same activity means you can use interface... or the adapter class in Another fragment means you can go with this

Answer (score 0):

You can get that fragment instance either by 'ID' or by tag (you would need to give a tag while adding this fragment).

Now you can call any public method of that fragment using its instance.

For Example (Using tag), if you want to call a public method 'show()' of FragmentA. Then while adding it to the activity give it a tag like this:

```
Fragment fragmentA = new FragmentA();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
.add(R.id.fragment_container,fragmentA,"YOUR_TARGET_FRAGMENT_TAG").commit();
```

And to get its instance (on a button click or as required):

```
FragmentA fragmentA = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("YOUR_TARGET_FRAGMENT_TAG");
fragmentA.show();
```

Answer (score -1):

Declare in your fragment the RecyclerView as public

Declare in your activity the fragment as variable

in your activity on click listener get the recyclerview with

```
fragment.recyclerview
```

Comment: Never do like such way. Always try to use listener interface for communication between 2 components.